# Run Parse Server with HTTPS Connection

Tags: node.js, parse-server

could anyone help me running a Parse Server with HTTPS Connection on my Debian machine?

I already use HTTPS for my websites like https://hrt100.de/ but the NodeJS will run always with HTTP.

Thanks a lot for every answer

Comment: Can you layer your Node application behind something like [Nginx](http://nginx.com) which does the TLS encryption for you? That usually makes it easier to get right, and your Node app can focus on just doing HTTP.

Comment: Ah ok. I use Apache2 witch is configured with the SSL certificates. But I don't know where to put in the cert infos in the parse server...

Comment: You normally don't need to. Get Apache `httpd` to forward to your Node app. You can even use [Passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Node.js-tutorial) to make this easier.

Comment: ok, but can you explain me what i have to do with the httpd?

Comment: so i looked for the httpd file but there is nothing... I installed the newest version of apache on my debian 8 system

Comment: Configure `httpd` with TLS for HTTPS, check that it's working with [a diagnostic tool](https://www.digicert.com/help/), then get it to forward to your Node.js application's HTTP port.